# Why should I use FragmentPagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I've been searching for it and all I found was the difference between them. And that's not the point.

If you use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in a `ViewPager`, you'll end up doing the same as you'd do with `FragmentPagerAdapter`, but consuming much less memory. If that's true, why should I use the `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

What is the advantages of using `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the advantages of using FragmentPagerAdapter?

Speed, particularly when you have an intermediate number of pages: enough to easily hold in memory but beyond the handful that `ViewPager` wants to hold onto itself. With `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, as the user navigates the pager, the adapter destroys some fragments and creates new ones. That takes time, both in terms of the direct Java code and in terms of the impact upon garbage collection. If you do not need that in some circumstance, why pay the price?

Comment: Good answer! I just didn't understand what is the impact on garbage collection  if I use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter `, since it doesn't keep the entire fragment in memory.
`FragmentPagerAdapter ` would have more impact on GC, would it?

Comment: @LennonPetrick: `FragmentPagerAdapter` has more impact on *memory*. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` has more impact on *GC*. Suppose that we have 10 pages. The user, being bored, swipes from the first page through all pages to the last, then swipes back to the beginning. `FragmentPagerAdapter` will create and hold onto 10 fragments, and so increase memory pressure. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, though, will create and destroy ~14 fragments along the way, forcing extra work for inflating layouts and such, and dumping a lot of garbage onto the GC's plate.

Comment: Got it! As `FragmentStatePagerAdapter ` keeps destroying and creating all, every time it destroys a fragment, all the garbage of it will be dumped directly to GC.
Great explanation!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

**FragmentStatePagerAdapter:**
If your page contains more fragments better to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter because it will save only state
of the fragment.
**FragmentPagerAdapter:**
Where as FragmentPagerAdapter will keep each fragment in memory as a result it will consume more moemory.

For example if you have around 3 fragments[in Viewpager] which contains less images/bitmaps better to go with FragmentPagerAdapter

For optimisation better to define **mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);**
Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Note that I said I know the difference between them. However, my question was if `FragmentPagerAdapter ` consumes more memory, why should I use it? Since `FragmentPagerAdapter ` does the same as `FragmentStatePagerAdapter `

Answer (score 1):

if your structure depend on nested fragment and if you need to use `childFragmentManager` on inner fragment you might have a stack problem with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. when i got this problem i've changed `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with `FragmentPagerAdapter` and it worked well.

Comment: and I'm also facing this problem with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` because I'm using `getChildFragmentManager()` and the problem is my view is not clicking. When I scroll it then click.